# CLP and ACL for multi-tenant app in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

Imagine a website that agregates online **ordering for many restaurants** and is built using parse.com.

In parse.com there is a **class** called **Order** where all of the orders are stored.

Each **order** belongs to one, and only one, restaurant.

When querying the Order class, each restaurant can **only read** (and write) **its own orders**. A restaurant should not see (and write) orders for other restaurants.

To solve this, I've tried using **one role per restaurant** and add the **restaurant-role** to the each restaurants order's **ACLs**.  So I've created one role for each of the Restaurants using the following naming taxonomy: Restaurant-[restaurantObjectId].

I have taken care that user's belong to their respective restaurant-role.

I've also fiddle with Class Level Permissions (CLPs) without results: either total access or total lack of access, none of access limited to restaurant data.

Any clues?

Comment: Only users and other roles can belong to a role.  Restaurants cannot.  To use ACLs you'll need to represent users' relationships with restaurants, and derive the user's roles from which restaurant they belong.

Comment: I did not add restaurants to a role. I've created one role for each of the Restaurants, using the following naming taxonomy: Restaurant-[restaurantObjectId].

Comment: Okay.  Sounds like your design is fine.  We know that parse works, so it must be some aspect of the implementation is mixed up.  When I have a problem like this, I set out to build a case that would hold up in court.  Present evidence that each step is taken:  setup the ACL, add a user to a role, present log/debugger/data-browser evidence that you did all of that right.  Then show a simple query and log evidence that it fails.  I predict that before you finish building your case you'll have figured it out.  Either that or you'll have the right stuff to put into an SO question.

Comment: One of the things that is not clear for me is the hierarchy of CLP and ACL. If I have some objects that have a restaurant role in their ACL, do I have to have that role in the CLP?

Comment: No.  Think of the two as distinct approaches.  If you can describe permissions for all objects uniformly, then CLP saves you a lot of effort.  Otherwise -- like in your case, where rows' permission's differ based on the row -- you should just forget that CLP exists.

Comment: So my CLP for the Order class should be empty, right?

Comment: Yes. It's useful for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one has to have make the Find operation available to the Public. Otherwise it gives the `not authorized` error.